# Intercept controller request with Authorize attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How can I intercept requests to a controller and check if the controller called has an [Authorize] attribute set? And if controller has it, How can override default implementation with my custom authentication routine?

thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
public class MyAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
         //your authorization logic here
    }
}
```

And use `[MyAuthorizeAttribute]` instead of `[Authorize]` on your controllers or actions

Comment: Thanks. But I do not want to introduce a new attribute. But hack existing [Authorize] attribute.

Comment: @enableDeepak as you wish, but in general, deriving from existing class means reusing part of its functionality and combining it with new functionality.